# How to Track adword conversion with no thank you page or conversion page?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have website that I am trying to track its conversion. It dont have any thank you or conversion page instead it is pop up inquiry form.
When someone filled the form after successful submission massage appear: **inquiry sent successfully.**

I want to track this massage that means someone successfully submitted the form.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using Google Analytics on the website, then it would probably be easiest to track the inquiry form as an event. Then you can define the event as a goal in Analytics and import this goal as a conversion into Adwords.

If this approach is not feasible, you can execute the conversion tag dynamically, but it's not possible to just use jQuery's `getScript()` or something similar, because Google chose to use `document.write` to insert the actual conversion pixel request into the DOM.
What you'll have to do is to overwrite `document.write` with a function simulates an output stream and then inject the written bytes into the page.

It's also possible to send the conversion-gif request yourself, but this is not completely trivial.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is place a hidden iframe with no src in the html, place the conversion code in a thank you page, and load it using jquery on form submit:

```
$('.iframe-container iframe').attr('src', 'path/to/file/thankyou.html');
$('.iframe-container iframe').load();
```